# How to define if @mentioned is subscriber? TMI.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

Trying to make little bot for my friend's twitch and want to make it define if "@mentioned" is a sub.
I decided to test if it define mods first but it always says "2"

```
client.on("chat", function (channel, user, message, self) {
if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!love")) {
 var loved = message.split(' ')[1];
 if (loved.mod || loved['user-type'] === 'mod'){
 client.action(channel, "1 ");  //says sth
      }
 else {
 client.action(channel, "2 ");//says sth different
      }
}
```

Comment: It might help you get an answer if you give some more context around your question and add appropriate tags. "Javascript" is too general for this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.mod
```

Is only available for user objects that are returned by the message handler. If you want to check if a mentioned user is a mod you have to request the chat list

```
function getAllChatters(channel, _attempts) {
  return rp({
    uri: `https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/${channel.replace('#','')}/chatters`,
    json: true
  })
  .then(data =>  {
    return Object.entries(data.chatters)
    .reduce((p, [ type, list ]) => p.concat(list.map(name => {
      return {name, type};
    })), []);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if(_attempts < 3) {
      return getChatters(channel, _attempts + 1);
    }
    throw err;
  })
}
```

Then filter it for only mods

```
function getModsOnline(channel) {
  return getAllChatters(channel)
  .then(data => {
    var mods = data.filter(chatter => chatter.type == 'moderators' || chatter.type == 'broadcaster').map(chatter => chatter.name);
    return mods;
  })
}
```

And then see if the user is in the list

```
function isModOnline(channel, username) {
  // This will only return true if the mod is online in chat aka in the chat list
  return getMods(channel)
  .then(mods => {
    return mods.includes(username);
  })
}
```

Keep in mind that

- This is for getting mods, not subscribers
- It will only work for mods that are currently in chat, that list tends to update rather slowly
- You need to work with promises here so

  const rp = require('request-promise');

and to use the value

````
```
  isModOnline(channel, username)
  .then(value => {
    // Code to work with the value here 
    console.log(`User is mod: ${value}`);
  })
````